# How to get all unique posiblity's out of a list?

Tags: c#, list, combinations

For my problem I have a list of a count larger then 6+. From that list I would like to make a list containing every possible combination of the original cards that is exactly 6 cards long. (they have to be unique and order doesn't matter)

so object 
01,02,03,04,05,06
is the same for me as
06,05,04,03,02,01

```
//STARTER list with more then 6 value's
List < ClassicCard > lowCardsToRemove = FrenchTarotUtil.checkCountLowCardForDiscardChien(handCards);
```

The solution i found and used:

public static List generateAllSubsetCombinations(object[] fullSet, ulong subsetSize) {
        if (fullSet == null) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null.", "fullSet");
        }
        else if (subsetSize < 1) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Subset size must be 1 or greater.", "subsetSize");
        }
        else if ((ulong)fullSet.LongLength < subsetSize) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Subset size cannot be greater than the total number of entries in the full set.", "subsetSize");
        }

```
    // All possible subsets will be stored here
    List<object[]> allSubsets = new List<object[]>();

    // Initialize current pick; will always be the leftmost consecutive x where x is subset size
    ulong[] currentPick = new ulong[subsetSize];
    for (ulong i = 0; i < subsetSize; i++) {
        currentPick[i] = i;
    }

    while (true) {
        // Add this subset's values to list of all subsets based on current pick
        object[] subset = new object[subsetSize];
        for (ulong i = 0; i < subsetSize; i++) {
            subset[i] = fullSet[currentPick[i]];
        }
        allSubsets.Add(subset);

        if (currentPick[0] + subsetSize >= (ulong)fullSet.LongLength) {
            // Last pick must have been the final 3; end of subset generation
            break;
        }

        // Update current pick for next subset
        ulong shiftAfter = (ulong)currentPick.LongLength - 1;
        bool loop;
        do {
            loop = false;

            // Move current picker right
            currentPick[shiftAfter]++;

            // If we've gotten to the end of the full set, move left one picker
            if (currentPick[shiftAfter] > (ulong)fullSet.LongLength - (subsetSize - shiftAfter)) {
                if (shiftAfter > 0) {
                    shiftAfter--;
                    loop = true;
                }
            }
            else {
                // Update pickers to be consecutive
                for (ulong i = shiftAfter+1; i < (ulong)currentPick.LongLength; i++) {
                    currentPick[i] = currentPick[i-1] + 1;
                }
            }
        } while (loop);
    }

    return allSubsets;
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n

Comment: So you want to generate all the combinations of `k` values from `n` values? like `n` choose `k` or `nCk` in statistics?

Comment: I want every unique combo of  "k"  objects from "n" values where lengt n is variable and where k lengt is alway's 6.

Answer (score 0):

This one is not from me, but it does the job!

```
List <ClassicCard> lowCardsToRemove = FrenchTarotUtil.checkCountLowCardForDiscardChien(handCards);
var result = Combinator.Combinations(lowCardsToRemove, 6);

public static class Combinator
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, int k)
    {
        return k == 0 ? new[] { new T[0] } :
          elements.SelectMany((e, i) =>
            elements.Skip(i + 1).Combinations(k - 1).Select(c => (new[] { e }).Concat(c)));
    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible this would work but i didn't test it. Because i would love to do a check when i get a possible subset. But thanks for the input

I found a solution and i post it undernet this for other people if they would look for something like this one day